# One more time, auto-pst-pdf does not work

Tags: auto-pst-pdf

I know several questions have been asked, and answered, on this site about `auto-pst-pdf` not working, but none of them seems to solve my situation with this package. I am reluctant to use `XeLaTeX` for typeface-related reasons, which is why I'd like to stick with `pdfLaTeX` for compilation.

I have Perl, I have `pdfcrop`, and I'm running `pdfLaTeX` with `-shell-escape`. The .log file doesn't seem to tell of any errors except for the well-known:

```
Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of Affinity-pics.pdf failed.
This warning occured on input line 124.

Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
Could not create Affinity-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
This warning occured on input line 124.
```

I'm using a just updated `MikTeX 2.9` install on Windows 10 and my MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}

%% I've tried with all the four possibilities regarding 
%% commented and uncommented lines below

%\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

%\ifpdf\else
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\psline(0,0)(2,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or about what to fix, would be welcome.

I've appended the output of `\listfiles` as per cfr's suggestion.

```
     *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
auto-pst-pdf.sty    2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
catchfile.sty    2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 pst-pdf.sty    2016/07/11 v1.2a PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
luatex85.sty    2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
pstricks.sty    2015/11/14 v0.62 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pstricks.tex    2016/06/09 v2.68 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2016/06/09 v2.68 `PST-fp' (hv)
 preview.sty    2010/02/14 11.89 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
   dvips.def    2016/07/10 v3.1a Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Perhaps you should add `\listfiles` and post the output here? I'm using TeX Live, so perhaps there's a version difference. Have you updated MikTeX as both admin *and* as user?

Comment: It works fine for me too. However note `auto-pst-pdf should be loaded *after* pstricks.

Comment: I have `pst-pdf` 1.2a from July. What about you @Bernard ? My `graphics` stuff is also newer in parts and so is `pstricks` and `dvips.def`, `pst-fp.tex` etc. If you are sure you are up-to-date, maybe MikTeX is not? I forget, though. Do you use MikTeX, Bernard?

Comment: Maybe a MikTeX issue? I can't test that, though.

Comment: @cfr: Sorry, it was my mistake. I ran the updating process again and this time my MikTeXinstallation became actually updated (for both user and admin). The list of files in the post mirrors the updating now. Nevertheless, the problem with auto-pst-pdf remains no matter whether the package is loaded after or before pstricks.

Comment: @cfr: I don't really know. Let's see if someone using MikTeX stops at this post and has something to say.

Comment: with an up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9 and `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` (I have no Perl installed) I have no problem withyour example.

Comment: @cfr: I do use MiKTeX (up-to-date), and I have the same version of pst-pdf as you.

Comment: random guess: are you putting your auxillary files into another directory somehow?

Comment: The only "by-product" file that I'm taking to a folder different from that of the main .tex file (the `\jobname.tex`, in this case with the name "Affinity.tex") is the .bak file, which goes to a subfolder therein. I don't know if this may help, but I'm getting the `\jobname-autopp.dvi,.log,.ps` files as a result of the compilation and I'm using `WinEdt 8.0`.

Answer (score 4):

This comment was useful to me:

> with an up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9 and `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` (I have no Perl installed) I have no problem withyour example. – Herbert Aug 24 '16 at 7:35

Here is the code I included in my preamble.

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```